# LAMP Sending email through sendmail are flagged like spam

Tags: sendmail, lamp, spam

I have a LAMP server on my ubuntu 13.04 x64 and i can send email using "sendmail".But the email that i send with this program, arrives me flagged like spam. I'm trying sending email with gmail account to another gmail account.This is my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain ghost
127.0.1.1   ghost
```

What can i do to send email correctly?